# Minimum difference between n elements

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am working on a project in C++. I have `n` elements of `int` and a `K`.

I need to find a way to get the `min{a1+a2+....+an} - K <= ε >= 0` with ε = smallest number.

The combinations of numbers can be `{a1+a2+a6}` or just `{a2}` or `{a2+an}`, I mean it's not like find (n k) combinations.

I am working on a small n (n < 15) so complexity is not an issue.

Comment: If complexity is not an issue - do you know what the brute force solution would look like?

Comment: Yes, i've allready written code for this but it wouldn't probably work for a high N so i want to find a better one just in case.

Actually N represents the "Buildings" of a player in L5R. He would never get more than 10-15 "Buildings" due to Deck size is [40-60] but i still want to be sure.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. You are looking for a sub-set of your numbers whose sum is closest to (and above) `K`?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood you. Yes, that's what iam looking for.
Sum - K must be >= 0 , so K <= Sum

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you find a polynomial solution to your problem, i.e., you can find a subset of numbers whose sum is closest to `K`.

Now imagine this algorithm:

```
- Find the subset of numbers with sum closest to K
- If (sum(subset) - K == 0)
-     return subset
- Else
-     return DOESNT_EXIST
```

What is this algorithm? A polynomial solution to [the subset-sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)!

Since it's very unlikely that P=NP, then it's very unlikely that you're ever going to find any scalable solution.

In other words, you're stuck with brute force.

Comment: Unless an [approximation](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10482) is good enough

Comment: @user2147971, feel free to upvote what answers were helpful to you and accept one that solves your problem.

Comment: @Shahbaz Upvoting requires having 15 rep yourself, so if you liked the question, you should upvote that first :) (I like both, so +1 to both the question and your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitmasks for brute force approach. Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 15;
    int a[] = {8, 6, 14, 3, 4, 11, 100, 24, 41, 56, 18, 22, 11, 39, 91};
    int k = 16;
    int best_sum = -1;
    int best_i = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if((i >> j) & 1) {
                sum += a[j];
            }
        }
        if(sum >= k && (best_sum == -1 || sum < best_sum)) {
            best_sum = sum;
            best_i = i;
        }
    }
    cout << best_sum << " ->";
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if((best_i >> j) & 1) {
            cout << " " << a[j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code would not work if you can't make the exact sum of K with the elements in the board

Comment: You could have tried it on such case to make sure that it works instead of wrongly assuming that it doesn't.

Comment: But i did. Set k = 1234 and run it. It will print the whole array whose sum is less than 1234

Comment: When all elements sum is less than K, it will not work because that case is not handled, I have written the code to show you how it works, you can place if condition yourself for special cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write pseudo code for this:

You could create a sort-able map with list of values. And to put in a map one value of a1..n element, and their value. and while inserting set compare method as <
map would look like:

```
[n] [value]
```

The list would be ASC

And to get the smallest number number, you would go trough list from the beginning and do + operation until mapelement[0] + mapelement[1] > e + K

and you will have a list of first elements of a map, with their n value